# Emulator does not show home screen after waiting more than half of hour

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-emulator, emulation

I made an android project in android studio & test it in real device it works fine but now i have not real device with me & want to run the project in Emulator. I install the `AVD` & `intelhaxm-android.exe` from the directory

```
C:\Users\INZI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
```

after that I created Virtual Device to test the app but when I run this it shows black screen with android printed in the centre of the device but does not show the home screen. I tried it with the

> Visualization technology Enabled in BIOS setting. what should I do now I waited about more than a half of the hour but its same.

Please help 
Thank you in advance

Comment: I used Nexus s API 22 target  Android 5.1.1

Comment: since you haven't accepted my answer, i'm assuming you haven't found a solution?

Comment: I tried it but it consumes a little more space but I have small machine specification @Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved the mentioned problem Emulator was not showing the home screen because

1. I have more size of virtual Device than Haxm
2. I haven't completely downloaded the API with which I was testing.

Now I set less size of Virtual Device & test the app with the lower API that I fully downloaded .... now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) which is a much smoother emulator than the default. Furthermore, you will not run into any problems while setting it up as the program handles everything for you. Of course, as you become more experienced, you will want to debug your apps on a real device but as you do not have access to one, Genymotion is your best option.